# Can I reset Notification Centre badge counter for Messages?

Tags: macos, notifications, ichat, messages

The new **Messages** beta app (based on iChat) is stuck with one incoming message.
Can I somehow reset the badge?

[image: Messages app with a badge]

Comment: You may try to send a test message to everyone you've ever messaged through that software. It'll pull up the previous conversations and may kick off that "unread" message.

Comment: @cksum: This. Exactly. Thanks. Would you mind posting it as an answer so that I could accept it?

Comment: Done. Glad it worked. Personally, I found that sometimes when I load Messages, it pulls up previous conversations. Other times I get a blank window. Can't seem to isolate the bug or reproduce it all the time. Hopefully Apple will fix these issues because on a whole, it seems very rough, even for a beta release.

Comment: Yeah. I experience these glitches with Jabber account, mostly.

Comment: Have the same issue. Thanks for asking this question!

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The correct answer to this issue isn't to message all your contacts.

First close the `Messages` app.

Then simply open up **Activity Monitor** and quit the **Dock** process to restart it.

Here's how it looks:

[image: Quiting Dock in Activity Monitor]

Your badge count should be reset after that.

PS: You can access Activity Monitor from Spotlight (<kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd>) by simply typing its name and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Edit: update thanks to @JjP and @Toland H

Comment: I suppose you're right. Thanks for the tip and welcome to Apple.SE!

Comment: Since this was the accepted answer, there's 1 additional step that you have to do before you restart the Dock process. And that is to quit the Messages app. (thanks to @JjP below)

Comment: Killing the dock didn't work for me (yes, I did quit Messages before).
I still have 1 unread message according to the badge.
It is a message to myself, which occurred when I texted (or was it a call) to my other iphone ... [![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mgPZB.png)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mgPZB.png) Clicking on the top entry of that dock icon menu does not help either: Messages does not show any message :-( Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No. Does not work.

Comment: In my case, __iMessages__ has an issue, not the Dock.

Comment: This doesn't work.

Comment: This did not solve the problem for me in Monterey 12.5 (21G72).

Comment: `Dock` does not appear as a process in Activity Monitor in Mac OS 12.6

Answer (score 20):

Before you kill **Dock** you need to close **Messages** to make it work. I had this issue on *Mountain Lion (Mac OS X 10.8.2)*. When **Messages** was open and I killed **Dock** it didn't help. But when I closed **Messages** and then killed **Dock**, the badge was gone and after opening **Messages** the unread messages appeared so I could read them.

Comment: Applies to Yosemite (OSX 10.10) as well. Had this issue receiving notifications for an SMS message received on iphone and could not mark it as read.

Comment: Killing the Dock will NOT help if iMessages has an issue. Sometimes it _could_ be the Dock. But in my case it's simply not it.

Comment: Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 11):

Try to restart the dock. In the Terminal located at `/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app` type:

```
killall -KILL Dock
```

Comment: It's a bit of a last resort but it can work. It worked for resetting Calendar for me.

Comment: Do you always need the `-KILL` flag?  Will including this flag obviate the need to close the Messages app?

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work

Comment: Does not work..

Answer (score 10):

Click and hold on the Messages icon in your dock. A context menu appears with unread messages. Navigate to the previously unlisted and unread message that way. Then "read" it.

[image: Messages dock icon with badge]

Comment: I wish that I could up this answer a 100 times! This is the only thing that has worked for me on Yosemite! P.S. Right clicking works as well, you don't just have to click and hold.

Comment: Agreed, I can't believe this isn't the number one answer.

Comment: There is no "new message" in my iMessage, it still shows the badge

Comment: This is not how the menu looks.

Comment: This worked for me in Monterey 12.5 (21G72)

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you may miss reading a message from a friend. And sometimes Messages may not pull up the previous conversations as it should (it is still in testing and I hope those bugs are worked out for the final product).

I would suggest sending a test message to all the previous contacts you've IM'ed. It'll pull up the respective conversation thread and hopefully kick off the unread message from your notification badge.

Comment: See user20228's response: restart the Dock.

Comment: @richarddas Don't down vote because the solution that worked for you was different. That's actually pretty arrogant. It solved the issue for the original poster and there is no law that says there is only one answer to a question. This isn't math.

Comment: I merely did that in order to indicate that it was not the best answer. Sending a message to every contact is hardly an optimal solution when fixing the problem on your local machine (without disturbing anyone else) is possible. I take your point though @cksum, thanks

Comment: @richarddas Voting down is not to be used in such a way. Especially in this case as it actually *solved* the original posters problem. If you find short answers (e.g., "just reboot dude") or false information, or something that is sloppy or not adequately researched, then mark it down. But marking down an accepted answer is just poor form. You can leave a note on the answer that worked for you (as you did) and up vote it, but down voting is not to be misused (or abused). It's a strong statement to down vote a question or an answer. Not voting is often sufficient.

Comment: thanks for the clarification @cksum Will be noted in future! :)

Answer (score 2):

Go to Terminal and write:

```
osascript -e 'quit app "Messages"'
osascript -e 'quit app "Dock"'
open -a Messages
```

That's all

Comment: Nope. It's not.

Comment: Does not work. Apple clearly does not care.

Answer (score -7):

I'm not certain how the badge works, but I suspect the bug isn't on your computer, it's on apple's iMessage server somewhere in the cloud.

To fix it, you would have to have access to their servers, which you don't have.

Basically, the solution is to stop using beta software if you are worried about glitches like this one.

Comment: This is an abysmal answer. And not what this community is about! Don't berate people for using beta software. If you don't know, then just move along and help those you can!

Comment: Very true, but this isn't a much better piece of "constructive" criticism either.

Comment: "I'm not certain…" >> "To fix it you would have to…" > "Basically, the solution is" — please only post an answer if you know the answer. (I don't mean to sound harsh, just trying to be constructive.)

Comment: This is the best answer, given that none of the other answers work and apple couldn't care less.